# knplabs Timestampable вместе с Translatable

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Использую knplabs doctrine behaviors. Есть следующие сущности

```
class Article {
    use Translatable;
    use Sluggable;
    use Blameable;
    use Timestampable;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function getId():int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }
}

class ArticleTranslation
{
    use Translation;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $description;

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;
    }
}
```

Проблема в том что поведения `Blameable`, `Timestampable` генерируют свои значения только при добавлении/обновлении сущности `Article`. Надо чтобы при изменении полей из сущности `ArticleTranslation` тоже срабатывали поведения `Blameable`, `Timestampable`. Как бы это сделать наиболее правильным способом?